Movie/show: psychic causes a cop to kill his partner
Can't remember if this was a show or a movie, but the basic plot was a woman/girl is taken by cops, and the cops mention that they can't look her in the eye or she'll be able to mess with their minds. Eventually the girl complains about needing to use the restroom and the cops agree to this, allowing her to go into a bathroom stall while they wait outside in the restroom. However her peeking through the doors of the stall she tells the cop that it's a shame what the other cop did to his brother. To which the cop replies "I don't have a brother" - and she goes along the sides of "I know" and the Cop loses his mind and kills his partner!
Never got to see the ending of this movie and it looked really interesting!

Doyou remember the year?

That's a scene from Push where Kira (Camilla Belle) is a pusher which is Someone..

has the ability to implant memories, thoughts and emotions into the minds of other people in order to manipulate them"

The scene goes as you described and here it's



